# Adding files to WebSharper.UI.Next project

Tags: websharper

As a way of playing with WebSharper.UI.Next I cloned the sample project from GitHub. It works but how do I add a file. It is possible to bring up the "Add Item" menue but a .fs file is not one of the options.

Answer (score 1):

this is a general problem for Visual Studio now, F# web projects don't list new file templates. There is a workaround by Daniel Mohl, also found here: https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/src/8ca312ae9cefb898eee5f435ef54599338793cfd/templates/sitelets-website/Setup.fsx?at=default

Run this script in FSI then restart VS.